How to plug a frame hole used for a rear mechanical derailleur?

I'm upgrading a Giant Propel from 2x mechanical Shimano 105 11s to 1x electronic SRAM Rival AXS 12s.
That leaves a few holes to be plugged, especially the rather big one used for the rear mech. There's also a small one for the front mech, as well as two big M4 bosses used for the front mech (same threads as the bottle cage bosses).
How do one best plug these?

Is your frame steel? If not, I wouldn't bother. Aluminum shouldn't rust that easily, and carbon fiber will obviously never rust (although it has its own problems related to fragility).

@juhist I would personally argue for still plugging them, it prevents any unexpected hitchhikers (that hole is easily large enough for many insects), as well as just generally keeping things clean.

You can get plugs in different forms and sizes. Search for "bike frame plugs" or "cable guide plugs".
There are many manufacturers making them, for example Sram or Jagwire.
For plugging the M4 Threads, the best solution is to just screw in M4 Button head screws. (Bottle cages typically are M5. Are you sure it's M4?)

Cut some cirles out of black tape to cover the holes (PVC electrical tape). Clear frame protector tape (helicopter tape) works well too, if it isn’t too thick. Or the sticker of your choice as long as it’s vinyl and the glue is ok for outdoor use.
The main problem with bungs and rubber inserts is that they fall out and disappear either when riding or if bumped during storage. They can also get pushed in too far and disappear into the frame.
